# Can you develop a app with xcode for just 1 device?

Tags: xcode

I have created an application in Xcode that just needs to be on 1 of my own devices, so no app store submission.

Is it safe to leave it builded from xcode (through usb) on my device, or will it get deleted by apple automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is "safe". It won't be deleted by Apple :)

There is no problem on mantain a debug build, only for yourself, directly from XCode. AFAIK, there is no limitations.